# JHEP template: Changing font size in the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize

I am using the JHEP template to write my dissertation. This is how the table of contents presently looks,[image]

In the document code, I wanted the section font to be bigger and hence I added `\Large` to the section definition. For example:

```
\section{\Large Introduction}.
```

But, this change in font size is being reflected in the table of contents. What should I do in order to have a uniform font size in the table of contents?

From some online lecture notes written in JHEP template, I am aware that it is possible to have different font sizes for section names within the document and in the table of contents.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you’re required to use a *template* to write your dissertation, then I don’t think it’s a good idea to change the design of the template (Are you sure you want to impose your own taste on your university’s requirement?).

Comment: @RuixiZhang I am not required to use any particular template. I chose JHEP as find its format pretty good. But, JHEP is for academic articles while I am writing a thesis. Hence, I would like to have titles of chapters with bigger font sizes which lead to the above problem.

Comment: I see. Please put your code fragment into a compilable document, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Using `JHEP3.cls` or using `jheppub.sty` may need different solutions. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Just modify ``\section`` by ``etoolbox``'s ``\patchcmd`` or  with ``titlesec``, and remove the manual ``\Large``.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions. My problem got solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the style file for JHEP, i.e., after the line

```
\usepackage{jheppub}
```

add the following lines:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\section{\large}{\Large}{}{}
%\xpatchcmd\subsection{\normalsize}{\normalsize}{}{}
%\xpatchcmd\subsubsection{\normalsize}{\normalsize}{}{}
```

This code replaces `\large` by `\Large` in all section titles. If you want to change also the size of sub-sections and sub-sub-sections, uncomment the corresponding line and replace the second `\normalsize` by the new size.

Don't add the font size `\Large` to the section title itself, since then the size command will be used everywhere the section title is used, including in the table of contents.

As an example, modify the preamble of `jhepexample.tex` (the sample file coming with the jhep style) to look like

```
\usepackage{jheppub} % for details on the use of the package, please
                     % see the JHEP-author-manual
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\section{\large}{\Large}{}{}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % if needed
```

(**without modifying anything else!**). Then the document will start like that:

[image]

For comparison, here is the output of the unmodified document:

[image]